# fix incorrect link through web.config by removing one section

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, web-config

a 3rd party supplier is sending out emails to our clients with an incorrect unsubscribe link. Until they can update this URL I'm looking to correct any requests through web.config.

The correct working link should be:

https://www.example.com/my-account/alertunsubscribe?email=[email]&searchname=[searchname]

The broken link in emails is:

http://www.example.com/property/myaccount/alertunsubscribe?email=[email]&searchname=[searchname]

I've been trying to use something like the following:

```
<rule name="AlertUnsub" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^property/myaccount/alertsubscribe" />
    </conditions>          
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/my-account/alertsubscribe" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I already have another rule re-directing non http traffic to https which works fine so I don't think I have to deal with that here. Same for non-www to www.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for a match with the URL not `{HTTP_HOST}` variable, so no condition required.

Try this instead:

```xml
<rule name="AlertUnsub" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^property/myaccount/alertunsubscribe" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="my-account/alertunsubscribe" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

BTW there's a confusion about `alertsubscribe` and `alertunsubscribe` in the question. I assume that it is `alertunsubscribe`.

Comment: Ahh, I checked my post 3 times over and didn't spot the missing "un" but you are right enough in your assumption! 

Anyway, almost immediately after posting I got it working but it was doing it for all urls beginning /property*    

Fixed now and working perfectly with your comment. I understand now.  Nice one cheers, have a great weekend!

Comment: @Johnathan I'm glad if I could help. You also have a good weekend!